# How to increase a counter in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have table `tags` which has a field `count` that indicates how many `items` have been tagged with the given tag.

How do I increase this counter in SQLAlchemy after I add a new item with an existing tag?

With plain SQL I would do the following:

```
INSERT INTO `items` VALUES (...)
UPDATE `tags` SET count=count+1 WHERE tag_id=5
```

But how do I express `count=count+1` in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you have something like:

```
mytable = Table('mytable', db.metadata,
    Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('counter', db.Integer)
)
```

You can increment fields like this:

```
m = mytable.query.first()
m.counter = mytable.c.counter + 1
```

Or, if you have some mapped Models, you can write alternatively:

```
m = Model.query.first()
m.counter = Model.counter + 1
```

Both versions will return the sql statement you have asked for. But if you don't include the column and just write `m.counter += 1`, then the new value would be calculated in Python (and race conditions are likely to happen). So always include a column as shown in the two examples above in such counter queries.

Comment: Thanks. But can you explain about race condition more? Did I understand you correctly that the first version would be safer than the second?

Comment: No. Both versions I've showed you are exactly the same (one uses mapped objects and the other tables). But the third statement with `+=` would  result in `SET counter=4` instead of `SET counter=counter+1`. So you shouldn`t use the third `+=` version.

Comment: And I just wrote an PostgreSQL-Function for that -.- However, I think I wrote m.counter = m.counter + 1 and this didn't work, so it seems you need to use either table or the classvariable (just to clarify)

Comment: Can you explain where mytable.c.counter comes from?  That's a syntax I'm not familiar with, and it seems like it refers to the table definition instead of the selected row 'm'... so I'm not clear on how the math works.

Comment: if you increment the actual value (e.g. 3 of type int) in Python, you will get a new integer (e.g. 4). If more clients do this concurrently, you might loose some updates. SqlAlchemy's column type has an overloaded __add__ operator, so writing "column + 1" would result in an object that tells the database (and not Python!) to increment the column by one.

Comment: Excellent point about the race condition - that's an easy one to get wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what the c is in `mytable.c.counter` or where it comes from.

Comment: I can't for the life of me find where in the documentation is the `Table.query` line.

Answer (score 55):

If you are using the SQL layer, then you can use arbitrary SQL expressions in the update statement:

```
conn.execute(tags.update(tags.c.tag_id == 5).values(count=tags.c.count + 1))
```

The ORM Query object also has an update method:

```
session.query(Tag).filter_by(tag_id=5).update({'count': Tag.count + 1})
```

The ORM version is smart enough to also update the count attribute on the object itself if it's in the session.

Comment: So sqlalchemy compiles everything in one query? or it sends a 'SELECT' and then an 'UPDATE'?

Comment: @Rutrus to be extra sure you can use a transaction session with `with session.begin():` and execute all commands in that code block. It commits or rollbacks automatically - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html

Answer (score 1):

Regarding @Leon comment you can rewrite code a little to avoid race condition.

```
async def inc_counter(id_: int):
    query = items.update(items.c.id==id_)
    return await db.execute(query, values={'counter': items.c.counter + 1})
```

P.S. If you a creating tables in class way you will need to access **table** attribute for that:

```
from sqlalchemy import update

async def inc_counter(id_: int):
    query = update(Items).filter(Items.id==id_)
    return await db.execute(query, values={'counter': Items.__table__.c.counter + 1})
```

Comment: I've deleted my post with the race condition to make it easier to find a better solution. Maybe you can edit your solution accordingly.