# How to update SQLite table based on checkbox value in Flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have SQLite database which contains data regarding products such as `Product Name`, `Description` and `Like` which shows if the user likes or doesn't like the product.

A user search for different products which populate a table with the name, description and a checkbox which is clicked in if the value of `Like` is 1 in the database and unchecked if not.
I have implemented the button through (as seen in `index.html`)

`<form method = "POST"> <input type="checkbox" name="like" {% if product.like == 1 %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}>`

I now want the user to be able to check and uncheck the boxes in the table, and then press a button that updates the `Like` column in the database, how do I do this?

(I can't even access the value of the button in `app.py`. When trying `print(requests.form['like'])` on the line after `name=requests.form['search']` it returns `BadRequestKeyError: The browser sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'like'`)

`app.py`

```
... 
product = []
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def index():
   name = None
   if request.method == 'POST':
     name = request.form['search']
     if name is not None or name != "":
        query_product = Products.query.filter(Products.productname==name).first()
        if (query_product is not None) and (query_product not in product):
            company.append(query_company)
   print(company, file = sys.stderr)
   return render_template('index.html', companies = company)
```

`Products` class

```
class Products(db.Model):
   index = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True)
   productname = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key = False)
   description = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key = False)
   like = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = False)
   ...more columns
```

`index.html`

```
 <!-- /templates/index.html  -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for Product.." name="search">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Search</button> <button type="submit" name="update" value = company.index style = margin-left:45%>Update</button>
    <div class="product-container" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 80vh">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table" id="products">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Like</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for product in products %}
                    <tr {{company.index}}>
                        <th scope="row">{{ product.productname}}</th>
                        <td> {{ product.description }} </td>
                        <td><form method = "POST"> <input type="checkbox" name="like" {% if product.like == 1 %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}></form></td>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to do this with javascript and add another route to your backend which then updates the database.

maybe something like this, if it should happen automatically:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="updateLike('productId', this.checked)">
<script>
async function updateLike(productId, doesLike) {
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost/products/productId/like", {
        method:"POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            productId: productId,
            like: doesLike
        })
    });
}
</script>
```

or you could add a button which sends the request to the server.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="like"/>
<button onclick="updateLike('productId', document.querySelector('input[name=like]').checked)">confirm</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you I will try this. How do I specify that it's my SQLite database that should be updated? which is  a SQLAlchemy() db object?

Comment: I have never heard of SQLAlchemy, I'm sorry. But maybe this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667138/how-to-update-sqlalchemy-row-entry