# How can I get/set an SqlAlchemy query value with the Column object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

To make some code more generic, I'm trying to retrieve/set values in a database row using the Column object.

For example, I'll have this setup:

```
col = MyTable.MyColumn
result = session.query(...).one()
```

Now I want to get/set the values, semantically like below:

```
cur_value = result[col]
result[col] = new_value
```

What is the correct syntax to use the Column object to get/set values in the result?

*`col` will not be a static value, but dynamically taken from a map.*

Comment: `cur_value =result.col, result.col = new_val db.session.commit()` als this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667138/how-to-update-sqlalchemy-row-entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
cur_value = getattr(result, col.key)
setattr(result, col.key, new_value)
```

Comment: The column objects are not strings, they are SqlAlchemy Column objects.  If I knew how to get the resulting name of that column, this would work.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y use: `col = MyTable.MyColumn.key`... this will give you your column name.