# Difference between different ways of updating a single row

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for the "standard" way of modifying a single row from a given table. (I want to modify several values within the row.)

I've found many ways and I struggle understanding the impact of this choice. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26920108/1720199) is an example of what I'm not looking for but also an example of the many ways of doing the same thing.

SQLAlchemy seems to be a well though tool so I guess there aren't several way just as a design consequence, there must be a benefit/cost for every solution. I'm looking for this information but I can't find it anywhere.

For the sake of the example, consider I want to update the profile of a given user with ID `user_id`. I can for example write the two following statements that (in appearance) the same effect:

```py
profile = {'display_name': 'test', 'age': 34} 

# 1)
user_profile = query.get(user_id)
for key, value in profile.items():
    setattr(user_profile, key, value)
database.session.add(user_profile)

# 2)
user_profile = query.filter_by(id=user_id)
user_profile.update({**profile})

# 3)
with database.engine.connect() as conn:
    stmt = (
        sqlalchemy.update(models.UserProfile)
                  .values(**profile)
                  .where(models.UserProfile.id == db_user_id)
    )
    conn.execute(stmt)
```

In general what are the performances impact of all the different ways of updating a single row using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: If considering only DB performance, 1) and 2) are identical, only resulting in an actual DB transaction when you run `session.commit()`. 3) is where the DB performance of SQLA might be under consideration, since it deals with the difference beween the ORM abstraction and raw-SQL operation. At that stage, choice of SQL provider, engine, and operating platform become somewhat relevant.

Comment: If you're curious you can use `create_engine(…, echo=True)` to see logging output of the statements that SQLAlchemy is generating.