# How can I implement the function of recording the view of an article in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I develop a blog system of myself, and I would like to implement the function that when a visitor visit an article, the view of the article will add 1, here is the model of my `Article` class:

`class Article(db.Model):

tablename = 'articles'

... 
num_of_view = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
...`

the `num_of_view` is the views of an article.
how can I do it ?  It is OK to use `db.event.listen` to implement my function?
I will appreciate it if you can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase a counter in SQLAlchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334824/how-to-increase-a-counter-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to record number of views is to do it in the GET request handler:

```
@app.route('/articles/<id>') 
def get_article(id):
    article = Article.query.get_or_404(id)
    article.views += 1
    db.session.add(article)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('article.html', article=article)
```