# SQLAlchemy - Find highest value less than specified value

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy Model which holds a list of products. In addition to the primary key, each product is allocated a sequential numeric product identifier (prod_id).

prod_id values >= 10000 are reserved.

When a new product is added I therefore need to allocate it the next available prod_id, which should be 1 greater than the highest current prod_id, ignoring any > 9999.

I can probably construct something in SQL but I'm struggling to form a SQLAlchemy query that will return that value.

I'm not worried about race conditions - this is a simplified example to illustrate the problem.

The Model:

```py
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    prod_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Where prod_id is the sequential product identifier (with prod_ids >=10000 reserved).

In pseudo code, I'm looking for a SQLAlchemy query equivalent to:

```py
next_prod_id = 1 + max(Product.prod_id where Product.prod_id < 10000)
```

So, as an example, if the existing table is ...

```
id    name        prod_id
1    Product A         1
2    Product B         2
3    Reserved A    10000
4    Product C         3
5    Reserved B    10001
6    Product D         4
```

... then next_prod_id needs to be 5.

Here's my stab at a query, but it isn't working (syntax error that I can't sort out):

```py
next_prod_id = Product.query(func.max(Product.prod_id)) \
           .filter_by(Product.prod_id < 10000) + 1
```

Comment: This might help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334824/how-to-increase-a-counter-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: I'm thinking I need to use func.max but having problems with the syntax (I've edited the question to add my attempt).

Comment: initialize variable to sort by descending of product ID , filter the product ID< 1000, and use limit(1)apply to variable. then insert variable +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, managed to get func.max to do the job.

Here's my solution - not sure if it is the most efficient but it works.

```py
next_prod_id = db.session.query(db.func.max(Product.prod_id)) \
                .filter(Product.prod_id < 10000) \
                .scalar() + 1
```